# Log error about Python remote development with PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, vagrant, pycharm

I want to finish the Python remote development with Pycharm followed by this instruction:https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2015/03/feature-spotlight-python-remote-development-with-pycharm/. Please check  it by this image.

[image: remote deployment]

I want my current local project directory `blueprintexampe` to be mapped to remote `/home/vagrant/blueprintremote`. Now I can right-click my project in the project view and select Upload to. But there is log error is shown as following:

```
 Upload to 192.168.33.10 failed: SSH_MSG_DISCONNECT: 2 Too many    
 authentication failures for vagrant
```

Do you know how to solve it?